# Database is not appearing in MongoVue

Tags: python-2.7, mongovue, pymongo-2.x

I am using MongoVue and Python library Pymongo to insert some documents. I used MongoVue to see the db created. It was not listed. However, I made a find() request in shell. I got all the inserted documents.

Once I manually create DB all the inserted documents appears then.Every other db's inside the localhost is not affected.

What is the reason for this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, found out the fix for this behavior. Refreshing in MongoVue didn't work. So, I had to close it and open the MongoVue again to see the newly created collections.